# Can I (how) create my own UITouch events that can be tied in to IBActions?

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, uitouch

I have a new gesture, (touch, drag onto other, release) which I would like to have behave the same as touchUpInside or touchDown or any of that list that pops up when you tie in IBActions in interface builder. (I.e. I want my custom ones on that list so I can tie them to IBActions)

Is there a way to do this or do I need to programmatically tie things together?

### Update: The Next Best Thing

Here's a very stripped down version of what I did that de-coupled my object from any other particular class, in case anyone else tries to accomplish this:

```
@interface PopupButton : UIView {

}

//These are the replacement "IBAction" type connections.
@property (nonatomic) SEL tapAction;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id tapTarget;

@property (nonatomic) SEL dragAction;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id dragTarget;

@end

@implementation PopupButton

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    //Your custom code to detect the event
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    //Your custom code to detect the event
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    //Here we'll say I detected the event I called "drag".
    if (!(self.dragTarget && self.dragAction)) {
        NSLog(@"No target for drag.");
        abort();
    } else {
        [self.dragTarget performSelector:self.dragAction];
    }

    //And here I detected the event "tap".
    if (!(self.tapTarget && self.tapAction)) {
        NSLog(@"No target for single tap.");
        abort();
    } else {
        [self.tapTarget performSelector:self.tapAction];
    }
}

-(void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    //Your custom code to detect the event
}

@end
```

Now to set this up, in the view controller I wanted to tie these actions I put this instead:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [equalsPopupButton setTapTarget:self];
    [equalsPopupButton setTapAction:@selector(equalsPress)];
    [equalsPopupButton setDragTarget:self];
    [equalsPopupButton setDragAction:@selector(isNamingResult)];
}
```

Not as elegant obviously as option+drag, but it gets the job done without making my code all rigid and attached. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to tie the functions this way. You should use an auxiliary function in code and call it from the IBaction function and the gesture recognizer function.

Comment: I was afraid that might be what I'd have to do.